# Scraping for a "preview" of a webpage - Python

Tags: python, html, django, screen-scraping

I'm indexing a list of links, these links update quite often so I'm automating thumbnails for the sites.

For most sites it's easy, as I just grab the biggest image on the page hoping it describes the content.

But other times there are videos as main content of the page.

---

Does somebody have tips with dealing with this? That would be great!

---

Regarding the usage of Webkit to create screenshots I [found this](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/)

Answer (score 3):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) uses an embedded copy of the WebKit render engine (used in Safari, Chrome etc.) to save a webpage to PDF, including all images (no Flash video though I guess). That could be a starting point for a much more accurate thumbnail.

Comment: This is great idea. I'll see what I can find. It would be **Great** if I can figure how to use this out.

Answer (score 3):

There exists (free and paid) services that do exactly what you need. I use [shrink the web](http://www.shrinktheweb.com):